# Get mp3 and json from AWS Polly at the same time with one call (saving cost)

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, mp3, text-to-speech, amazon-polly

I asked a question here, and answered couple of seconds later by myself: [Get mp3 and speech mark from Amazon Polly using NodeJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57022394/get-mp3-and-speech-mark-from-amazon-polly-using-nodejs)

I wonder if I have to make two calls to get json and mp3 of my text?

```
let params = {
    'Text': 'Hi, my name is Soley. We are building something amazing!',
    'OutputFormat': 'json',
    'VoiceId': 'Matthew',
    'SpeechMarkTypes': ['word', 'sentence']
}
```

and

```
let params = {
    'Text': 'Hi, my name is Soley. We are building something amazing!',
    'OutputFormat': 'mp3',
    'VoiceId': 'Matthew'
}
```

it seems polly ui https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/polly/home/SynthesizeSpeech do them separately as well ?

[image]

^ no download link for mp3, just play button when requesting json.

Answer (score 1):

the SynthesizeSpeech API can only take one parameter for the output format, so yes, you have to call it twice.

```
 OutputFormat

    The format in which the returned output will be encoded. 
    For audio stream, this will be mp3, ogg_vorbis, or pcm. 
    For speech marks, this will be json.

    When pcm is used, the content returned is audio/pcm in a signed 16-bit, 
    1 channel (mono), little-endian format.

    Type: String

    Valid Values: json | mp3 | ogg_vorbis | pcm

    Required: Yes
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/API_SynthesizeSpeech.html